# How To Resolve Google's "Invalid Format of DKIM Record" Error Message?

Tags: dns, mail-server, mailenable

**Environment:** Personal Mail Server (ie, private machine at my personal business)
**Environment:** Public DNS Server (ie, I use my registrar's interface)
**Configuration Part 1:** Created a **DKIM** Record from my Personal Mail Server
**Configuration Part 2:** Loaded the **DKIM** Record onto my registrar's Public DNS Server

**Problem:** Google's MX Toolbox Throws an Error Message
**Google Error Message:** "Invalid Format of DKIM Record"

```
DKIM Record ≈ "p=DKIM1; p=blahblahblahMahMahMah;"
```

Attempt A: Breaking the "p" tag into smaller, space-delimited chunks (each ≤ 256 characters)
Attempt B: Wrapping the tags in double-quotes
Attempt C: Using various encryption methods (ie, 512-bit vs 2048-bit, etc.)
Attempt D: A combination of attempts A-C

May you please tell me how I can resolve the error message that Google's MX Toolbox throws when analyzing my DKIM Record?

Thanks!

Elias

Sidenote: other MX tools don't have any issue with my DKIM Record (eg, MXToolbox.com)

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

**Add the K tag**

```
DKIM Record ≈ "p=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=blahblahblahMahMahMah;"
```

**or**

```
DKIM Record ≈ "p=DKIM1; k=rsasha; p=blahblahblahMahMahMah;"
```

Apparently, Google's current MX Toolbox does not automatically use a **k tag** as a default. Therefore, you must ensure your TXT record has it.

Good news: You no longer have to space-delimit the p tag to satisfy Google's MX Toolbox.